# Rebase branch against origin/master in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: git, intellij-idea, rebase

When developing feature on branch I'd like to rebase it frequently with `origin/master`.

The option `Update Project...` (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) would be great, as it can be configured to do stash, rebase and unstash. However, by default it rebases against tracking branch, which is not `origin/master` and I don't want to change it (I want to track the branch for which pull request is raised).

**Is there any way in IntelliJ to do a stash, rebase origin/master and unstash with one keyboard shortcut?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To assign a shortcut to `Git -> Rebase...`, just open the Keymap setting and assign it any key combination you want to have. There you can select what to rebase from where to where.

Or by using the mouse you can click in the status bar on the lower left on `Git: <feature>` and then select `origin/master` to rebase onto it.

If you need `stash -> rebase origin/master -> unstash` on one keypress, I guess you have to write some script that does it, then add this as external tool to IDEA and then assign that external tool any shortcut you like.

Comment: I know about `Rebase...`, but this is not one keypress as you noticed. External tool is nice idea. However, is it possible to open `Resolve Conflicts` window automatically on conflicts like `Update Project...` does?

Comment: I don't know. If not you still have one more option left. Develop a small IDEA plugin that provides one action with a key binding that does stash, rebase, unstash and opens the conflict resolution dialogue when appropriate. :-)

Comment: All right, that's always an option :) However, I assume thousands of people must be already doing it somehow, as this is very typical workflow I suppose. And I don't believe everyone's using custom scripts or each time   using slow way through `Rebase...` window.

Comment: Well, I usually use the commandline. ;-) I figured out another way that may work for you. You can record Macros of actions you do. So if you use `Edit -> Macros` and start recording a macro, then use the `Rebase...` action that might work for you. You can also then edit the Macro by hand in the file `<IDEA settings>/config/options/macros.xml`

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Vampire's comment I've found efficient way to do it in IDEA using `External Command`. Just configure it like below and attach shortcut to it:

[image]

Magic is done by super-powerful and fast `git pull --rebase --autostash origin master`.
Note: it works only with Git 2.7+.